# How to check if all records have the same value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery Standard SQL, I have a table with three fields A, B, C.

I'm struggling to build a query that will group the data by fields A and B and then only return those records where all the values of field C are the same. Field C can have any value, but they all have to be the same value.

Like:

[image]

In the example shown above, the query would only return Coventry/Fred because all its values in 'C' are the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share an example input and expected output?

Comment: I've expanded my original question to include an exampl.e

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `having count(distinct c) = 1`:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'Coventry' as A, 'Fred' as B, 'Wood' as C union all
    select 'Coventry' as A, 'Fred' as B, 'Wood' as C union all
    select 'Bristol' as A, 'Joe' as B, 'Wood' as C union all
    select 'Bristol' as A, 'Joe' as B, 'Metal' as C
)
select A, B
from mytable
group by A, B
having count(distinct c) = 1
```

[image]